# Badger's FizzBuzz

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

I love the [badger's song (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIyixC9NsLI), so I wrote a FizzBuzz about it.

The thing is, I've been writing Javascript for years but I'm still not sure about the best practices. So FizzBuzz seemed a simple trial for me to write some code and make it reviewed!

```
function FizzBuzz(limit){
    var _limit = limit;

    var fizzBuzzContent = 
    [
        {"modulo":3, "word":"Badger"},
        {"modulo":5, "word":"Mushroom"},
        {"modulo":15, "word":"Ooohhh it's a snaaaakkkeeee"}
    ];

    this.calculate = function(){
        for(var counter = 1; counter <= _limit; counter++) {
            var line = counter.toString();

            fizzBuzzContent.forEach(function(e){

                if(counter % e["modulo"] === 0){
                    line = e["word"];
                }
            });

            console.log(line);
        }
    }
}
```

It would be called this way:

```
var f = new FizzBuzz(100);
f.calculate();
```

Is there something in this JavaScript object that's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few of things (apologies for repeating points from other answers; I wrote this earlier but didn't have a chance to finish it):

- Didn't know you could "love" that song. But you can certainly be brainwashed by it. See a doctor.
- Perhaps `BadgerMushroom` would be a more appropriate name?
- I don't think this needs to be a constructor. It could just be a plain function, which would be simpler.
- Constructor or not, you don't need to copy the `limit` argument to `_limit`. It's makes no difference (the argument is effectively already a local variable, and numbers are passed by value, not by reference, so they don't need cloning or stuff like that to avoid side-effects).
- `calculate` is not the greatest name. Yeah, it does do some calculation, but its main output is log messages. So perhaps `print` or similar would be a better fit.
- You don't need to quote keys in an object unless they contain spaces or other non-valid literals. Just writing `{ modulo: 5, word: "..." }` works fine. (You *can* quote them, of course, which is why JSON, where quotes are required, is valid JavaScript.)

  And since those keys work as regular property names, you can just write `e.modulo` and `e.word` - no need for brackets.

  Though for something so self-contained as this, I'd be fine with just nested array instead. True, you have to write `[0]` and `[1]` instead of `.modulo` and `.word`, but it's not as repetitive to define the lookup.
- Instead of `forEach`, I'd stick to a simple old `for` loop - that way, you can `break` out of it when you get a match.
- No need for `toString` on a number. It'll print the same.

So with that, something like this would do the trick too:

```
function badgerMushroom(limit){
    var line,
        words = [
            [15, "Ooohhh it's a snaaaakkkeeee"],
            [5, "Mushroom"],
            [3, "Badger"]
        ];

    for(var n = 1 ; n <= limit ; n++) {
        line = null;
        for(var i = 0, l = words.length ; i < l ; i++) {
            if(n % words[i][0] === 0) {
                line = words[i][1];
                break;
            }
        }
        console.log(line || n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer +1. Wouldn't be better to bring `words` array outside of the function such that you do not recreate this object every call? Especially since `words` shouldn't change:)

Comment: @tkellehe I wouldn't worry. Any JS interpreter from the past decade or two will optimize that away. I'd rather have the words defined where they're used, than have them float around next to - but independent of - the function. Of course, you can always define the function as the return value of an IIFE, and have the words as a closure. Then you're sure they're only defined once. But that's a little out of scope for this review.

Comment: That makes more sense:) Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

1. I don't see the point of introducing a private variable `_limit` when its value is never written to.  Why not just use `limit` from the arguments?
2. Using variable names such as `e` are meaningless
3. `fizzBuzzContent` can be modified to use direct array indices, rather than store an array of objects:

```
var fizzBuzzContent = [];
fizzBuzzContent[3] = "Badger";
fizzBuzzContent[5] = "Mushroom";
fizzBuzzContent[15] = "Oooh";
```

Personally, I think this looks more elegant, but your mileage may vary.

4. Using `.toString()` on `counter` isn't necessary, unless you don't want blue numbers in the developer console
5. Spacing around brackets makes code look cleaner and can aid readability
6. Preincrementing is proven to be slightly faster than postincrementing, but with only 100 iterations, it's meaningless.  Still may be worth knowing!

With these suggestions, and without changing any logic, this is FizzBuzz:

```
function FizzBuzz(limit) {
    var fizzBuzzContent = [];
    fizzBuzzContent[3] = "Badger";
    fizzBuzzContent[5] = "Mushroom";
    fizzBuzzContent[15] = "Ooohhh it's a snaaaakkkeeee";

    this.calculate = function() {
        for (var counter = 1; counter <= limit; ++counter) {
            var line = counter;
            fizzBuzzContent.forEach(function(word, index) {
                if (counter % index === 0) {
                    line = word;
                }
            });
            console.log(line);
        }
    }
}

console.clear();
var f = new FizzBuzz(100);
f.calculate();
```

Answer (score 3):

Storing data inside an object, inside an array is extraneous, when you're using key values for everything.

Try this kind of data structure instead:

```
var fizzBuzzContent = {
    "3": "Badger",
    "5": "Mushroom",
    "15": "Ooohhh it's a snaaaakkkeeee"
}
```

And instead of implicitly storing this layout inside the function, let's make it dynamic and add the 'options' as a parameter, defaulting to the original FizzBuzz if you don't provide your own options. Additionally defaulting to the original `30` limit from the question.

```
options = options || {
    3: "Fizz",
    5: "Buzz",
    15: "FizzBuzz"
};
limit = limit || 30;
```

---

`this.calculate`: It's not really an accurate name, there's not a 'calculation' done, you just start the FizzBuzz process.

`counter`: Really just `i` or `index` works fine.

---

`forEach`: Some people aren't particularly a fan of `forEach` and if your build's target audience can't support ES5, then you either need to use a polyfill or something else.

Personally, I'm an advocate of `forEach`.

As it's a prototype of `Array`, you can't directly use objects.

*But you just suggested an object...*

`Object` has a handy function on it that gets all the keys in the object as an array. By traversing this, you can use the first parameter only in `forEach`:

```
Object.keys(options).forEach(function(key){
    ...
}
```

---

`line = counter.toString()`: This is JavaScript, making a variable stay in the same type is not a feature of the language, you needn't worry if `line` becomes an integer, it won't cause issues.

---

Instead of assigning `line` you could just use a ternary statement `return`/`console.log` instead:

```
console.log(
    index % key === 0
    ? options[key]
    : index
);
```

---

### Putting that together:

```
function FizzBuzz(limit, options){
    limit = limit || 30;
    options = options || {
        3: "Fizz",
        5: "Buzz",
        15: "FizzBuzz"
    };
    this.startLoop = function(){
        for(var index = 1; index <= limit; index++) {
            Object.keys(options).forEach(function(key){
                console.log(
                    index % key === 0
                    ? options[key]
                    : index
                );
            });
        }
    }
}
var badgersSongOptions = {
    3: "Badger",
    5: "Mushroom",
    15: "Ooohhh it's a snaaaakkkeeee"
};
var limit = 100;
var BadgersSong = new FizzBuzz(limit, badgersSongOptions);
BadgersSong.startLoop();
```